# ErrorHandler is not catching some thrown errors

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular.
Why ErrorHandler is not catching errors that are thrown on the "first" loop?

error handler class

```
@Injectable()
export class RavenErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    handleError(err: any): void {
        console.log('handleError', err);
        Raven.captureException(err.originalError || err);
    }
}
```

code inside random component

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('init');

    // This is not caught for some reason
    throw new Error('Test error')

    // This is ok
    setTimeout(() => {
      throw new Error('Test error 3')
    }, 1)

    // This is catched correctly
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reject(new Error('Test error 2'))
    });
  }

  handleButtonClick() {
    // OK
    throw new Error('test error 4')
  }
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  ...,
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: RavenErrorHandler}],
  ...,
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: What is `the "first" loop`?

Comment: I don't know how to call that. All caught errors were thrown in next tick after ngOnInit

Comment: I got it. I don't see why it wouldn't work this way. Can you try to reproduce in plunker, stackblitz.com or similar?